# How to use multiprocessing in creating constraint in ORTool

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, or-tools

I am using ORTools to solve an optimization problem. Because the number of my constraints are so many and it needs many time, I decided to use multiprocessing to create and define them. this is some part of my code:

```
def constraint_saz(constraints,i):
    constraints[i] = solver.Constraint(1,10)
    "creating constraints[i].SetCoefficient"


if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager = Manager()
    constraints = manager.list(range(N))

    for i in range(N):
        p = Process(target=constraint_saz, args=(constraints,i))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

But I got this error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle SwigPyObject objects
```

What is the wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends:

- **Linear solver**: Should be possible, but there is currently no API for that.
- **Original CP solver** and the **routing library**: Not available
- **CP-SAT**: A parameter specify how many threads to use (num_search_workers).